# Can I speed up a fairly simple select query over timestamps?

Tags: mysql

I have what I believe is a very basic query but it is taking a very long time to run.

Specifics of my MySQL Server:

- Ubuntu Server 14.04, 64-bit running as a VMWare Workstation virtual machine
- 2GB of RAM dedicated to the VM

The table I'm running the query on has 33 columns: a timestamp, and 32 columns with well names (e.g. LEW91_4). There are about 2.5 million records in the table currently. The well columns are of datatype float. Indexes are:

- Column: ndx, Index: PRIMARY
- Column: t_stamp, Index: C1_Flowst_stampndx

The Query:

```
    SELECT 
     DATE_FORMAT(t_stamp, '%m/%d/%Y %h:00 %p') as 'Date',
     AVG(LEW91_1R97) as 'LEW91_1R97',
     AVG(LEW91_2R97) as 'LEW91_2R97',
     AVG(LEW91_3R97) as 'LEW91_3R97',
     AVG(LEW91_4) as 'LEW91_4',
     AVG(LEW97_1) as 'LEW97_1',
     AVG(LEW97_3) as 'LEW97_3',
     AVG(LEW97_4) as 'LEW97_4',
     AVG(LEW97_6) as 'LEW97_6',
     AVG(LEW97_7) as 'LEW97_7',
     AVG(LEW97_8) as 'LEW97_8',
     AVG(LEW97_12) as 'LEW97_12'

    FROM C1_Flows
    WHERE DAY(t_stamp) = 28
    AND MONTH(t_stamp) = 09
    AND YEAR(t_stamp) = 2015
    GROUP BY DAY(t_stamp), HOUR(t_stamp)
```

The query is currently taking roughly 11 seconds to run when I run it from MySQL Workbench. When it runs from within the Java-based interface I'm using to develop an HMI, it times out with the specific error "Read timed out."

I've run much more complex queries on similar servers (i.e. joins, unions, if statements, etc.) and they run faster than this one. Is there a way I can speed this up or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What is the result when omitting all the averages from the output However, 'read timed out' when called from a different (Java) context sounds .. curious. Is the timeout set to something practical?

Comment: After WHERE clause filtering, how many records remain?

Comment: put an index on t_stamp and use `WHERE t_stamp = '2015-09-28'` and see if there's an improvement

Answer (score 5):

Do not use

```
WHERE DAY(t_stamp) = 28
AND MONTH(t_stamp) = 09
AND YEAR(t_stamp) = 2015
```

use instead

```
WHERE t_stamp >= '2015-09-28' AND t_stamp < '2015-09-29'
```

or

```
WHERE t_stamp >= '2015-09-28' AND t_stamp < ADDDATE('2015-09-28', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

And have an index over t_stamp.  Doing the way you wrote, every record need a calculation on where clause, and index can't be used.

Comment: This won't work because it will only match `t_stamp` if it's exactly midnight.

Comment: This is where having a `DATE` field helps considerably. You want to avoid logical branches and function calls in your `WHERE` clause if you're concerned about speed.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN '2015-09-28 00:00' AND '2015-09-28 23:59:59'
```

to match all timestamps on that date.

This will make use of the index.